Microphone Access in Salesforce Mobile (LWC)
I want to access my microphone from LWC, which I’ll be running on the Salesforce Mobile App.
This is my code:
async startRecording() {
    try {
        this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream);
        this.audioChunks = [];

        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            this.audioChunks.push(event.data);
        };

        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
            const audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
            this.audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

            this.template.querySelector('audio').src = this.audioUrl;
        };

        this.mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
    }
}

Interestingly, this works on iOS and Windows, but not on Android. It returns NotReadableError immediately after I run the first line of code (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia).
I’ve granted the Salesforce App all the necessary permissions, including the microphone. But honestly, it doesn't seem to check any permissions, because whether I grant them or not, it just returns the same error.
Is this a known issue, or is there something more I need to do?
I also tried implementing Adapter.js, but it didn’t help.
import adapterjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/adapterjs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

async connectedCallback() {
    await loadScript(this, adapterjs);
}


Facing the same issue, have you found any solution?
